# Magento: "configForm is not defined" error when saving admin settings

Tags: magento, admin

I get this error when I try to save an some settings on the admin. At least so far, I've noticed it happens in the system/advanced section and on a plugin (color picker) I want to deactivate.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: configForm is not defined 
onclick
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the /magento/js/prototype/validation.js corrupted.

Just replace it with the original version from backup files or from fresh magento and it will works.